# How many JVM invoked by Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jvm

I use java -jar jenkins.war and java -jar slave.jar to run Jenkins master and slave. I want to know how many JVM invoked by Jenkins and I can configure the parameter of them.

**In Master:**

- I think only one JVM (I don't run job in master)

**In Slave:**

- java -jar slave.jar => one JVM
- every job have a new JVM, this JVM runs pre-build step, get source code (SVN, GIT, ...), post-build step
- every Maven will have its own JVM every Junit will have its own JVM

Another question is, I can set the JVM for slave in management node's advanced section, but who use it's configuration?

Comment: But if Maven build use the same JVM, why we can setup the JVM parameter of Maven?

Answer (score 3):

Every Maven build does not run in its own JVM. Java is multi-threaded. When you launch a slave you can configure the number of threads it can handle, same goes for the master.

Typically you run builds on slave nodes. On unix systems these can be setup to be automatically run from the master on remote nodes.

```
Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> New Node
```

Under Launch Advanced options you can specify the JVM parameters for the remote JVM running the Jenkins node software.

Each option has help, for example the "# executors" option:

> This controls the number of concurrent builds that Jenkins can perform. So the value affects the overall system load Jenkins may incur. A good value to start with would be the number of processors on your system.
>
> Increasing this value beyond that would cause each build to take longer, but it could increase the overall throughput, because it allows CPU to build one project while another build is waiting for I/O.
>
> When using Jenkins in the master/slave mode, setting this value to 0 would prevent the master from doing any building on its own. Slaves may not have zero executors, but may be temporarily disabled using the button on the slave's status page.